# How to convert string into array split and check whether last value is integer or not?

Tags: ruby, string

How can I convert `"flay1"` into array like `["f","l","a","y","1"]` and it should return true beacause last value contains `1`

Comment: I cannot parse your "sentence".

Comment: If you want to return `true` or `false`, depending on whether the last character of the string is `1`, `"flay1"[-1] == '1'` will do. There's no need to split the string into an array of its characters unless you want to make array the value of a variable. Either you believe it's necessary to split the string to examine the last character (incorrect) or you want `a = str.split('')`. You should clarify (by editing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input.match(/\d$/)
```

The regex matches if the string ends with a digit and returns `nil` if it didn't. It is an idiom in ruby to use raw values instead of necessary converting them to `true` or `false`. `nil` and `false` are the only falsy values.

```
if input.match(/\d$/)
  # do something...
end
```

If you really need the boolean result, you can double negate:

```
!!input.match(/\d$/)
```

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is because there's no point in splitting unless you save the array of characters to a variable; i.e., `"flay1"[-1] =~ /\d/` is more direct (even though the OP asked for `split`). I suspect that if you had you written `a = input.chars; a.last =~ /\d/`, you would not have received the downvote.

Comment: @CarySwoveland good point. I mindlessly did what OP asked me to. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this. But you can split the string into its individual parts and try to convert the last element into an integer. This is not very readable code, though, and it's here just to show that you can get the job done if you need to.

```
def last_char_is_int?(input)
  !!Integer(input.chars.last)
rescue ArgumentError
  false
end
```

Example:

```
last_char_is_int?("flay1") #=> true
last_char_is_int?("flays") #=> false
```

You can do with the double negation if you are willing to accept an integer as a true value. This way an integer, which can be treated as true, or false will be returned.

```
  Integer(input.chars.last)
```

The argument error would happen if the element could not be converted into an integer.

Comment: I think you misread the question. The OP wants to know if the last character is `'1'`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland actually he wants to know if the last character is integer (according to the title) rather than just `'1'`.

Comment: @ndn, right, I got that mixed up from Mohamad's answer, as I was referring to the last character as opposed to any character. Note I got it right in my comment on your answer. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland you are right, I did. I'll delete this.